# Compare values per row

Tags: python, pandas

For building an ensemble model I want to create a table with all results of a classification. Next I want to calculate per row the amount of different values and find the most frequent value.

---

Let's say the initial table looks like:

```
+----+--------+--------+--------+
|    |   col1 |   col2 |   col3 |
|----+--------+--------+--------|
|  0 |      1 |      2 |      3 | <- 3 different values, no most frequent one, take largest (3)
|  1 |      2 |      2 |      2 | <- 1 value, 2 is most frequent
|  2 |      3 |      2 |      2 | <- 2 values, 2 is most frequent
+----+--------+--------+--------+
```

If there is no most frequent one, like in this example in `row 0`, it should take the largest one - in this example it would be `3`.

Final result should look like:

```
+----+--------+--------+--------+--------------------+-----------------+
|    |   col1 |   col2 |   col3 |   different_values |   most_frequent |
|----+--------+--------+--------+--------------------+-----------------|
|  0 |      1 |      2 |      3 |                  3 |               3 |
|  1 |      2 |      2 |      2 |                  1 |               2 |
|  2 |      3 |      2 |      2 |                  2 |               2 |
+----+--------+--------+--------+--------------------+-----------------+
```

I know how to solve it column by column, but I'm struggling with row by row.

---

**MWE**

Data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1":[1,2,3],
    "col2":[2,2,2],
    "col3":[3,2,2]
})
```

Result:

```
df["different_values"] = [3,1,2]
df["most_frequent"] = [3, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `nunqiue` and `mode`

```
df["most_frequent"] = df.mode(axis=1) # when there is only one most freq value return
#df.mode(axis=1).max(1) #if there is more than one same freq value
#df.mode(axis=1).min(1) # for get the smallest 

df["different_values"] = df.nunique(axis=1)
df
Out[73]: 
   col1  col2  col3  different_values  most_frequent
0     1     2     3                 3              3
1     2     2     2                 1              2
2     3     2     2                 2              2
```

Comment: I knew there must be such an easy solution. Thank you very much. Upvote. And if I wouldn't take the largest value but the slowest, is there als such an simple way?

Comment: Nice solution, although im wondering, if you do it in two lines as you did, doesn't the `mode(axis=1)` part then use the value in new column as well which could sometimes change the result?

Comment: @ewz93 correct let us switch the line

Comment: @Marco_CH check the update with #